# Incrementing ID number manually in database VB.net

Tags: database, vb.net

i'm trying to increment the primary key, which is an ID number in this case, manually and not using SQL or OleDBConnection or anything like that. Ideally, what i'm trying to do is when a new record is saved, go to the last record in the database, extract the id number from that record, plus one to it, and set that new number as the ID for the new record. however, I can't figure it out for the life of me. heres what I have:

```
Dim max As Integer
Dim id As Integer
Dim lastrow As Integer

max = Database1DataSet1.Table.Rows.Count

For i = max To max

    Dim column As DataColumn = Database1DataSet1.Table.IdColumn
    lastrow = Database1DataSet1.Table.Rows(max).ToString

Next i
```

I have 17 records in the database, and the error that I keep getting is ' There is no row at position 17.

Comment: Why not let the database do it in the way it's designed to do?  What happens if you have two connections both trying to run your code?

Comment: What kind of loop you want with `max To max`?

Comment: A dataset isn't the database. This should be done in the insert query. (It should be For i = 0 To max-1)

Comment: Another way is to use a separate table with a row that holds the next value for the PK of your target table. Fetch and increment this value each time you insert a new row in your target table. The Fetch and Increment operation, however you do it, needs to be carefully designed to avoid possible race conditions eg use a transaction. The advantage of this is that you know what your PK is going to be ahead of the INSERT operation, which can be handy in some scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

All collections are zero based in .NET, so your loop needs to go until `max-1`. But in this case you don't want a loop but the last row

```
Dim lastrow = Database1DataSet1.Table.Rows(Database1DataSet1.Table.Rows.Count - 1)
Dim maxIdValue = lastrow.Id
```

But since it's not guaranteed that the last row contains the max-id-value you could also use `Linq-To-DataSet`:

```
Dim maxIdValue = Database1DataSet1.Table.AsEnumerable().Max(Function(r) r.Id)
```

But in general you should let the database do this, otherwise it's a race condition.